# Node/IO.js require from project root?

Tags: node.js

Let's pretend I have a project structure like so:

```
root/
|
-- app.js
-- config.json
-- package.json
-- lib/
   |
   -- config/
      |
      -- config.js
```

Further, let's pretend I want to read the root `config.json` from within the `config.js` (to override default configuration). I can do the following:

```
const path = require('path');
let jsonConfig = {};
try {
  let moduleDir = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename);
  jsonConfig = require(`${moduleDir}/config.json`);
} catch (e) {}
```

My question is, should I? The [documentation states](https://iojs.org/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule):

> Alternate way to retrieve require.main. The difference is that if the main module changes at runtime, require.main might still refer to the original main module in modules that were required before the change occurred. Generally it's safe to assume that the two refer to the same module.

I don't know what conditions would cause my main module to change at runtime. I assume it would be something that I would explicitly do myself, but I'm not familiar enough with the internals of the runtime to know for sure.

**Edit for clarification:**

I know that I could use a relative path, e.g. `require('../../config.json')`. But that makes it more difficult to refactor/move `lib/config/config.js` at a later date *if* that's something I end up doing. Thus my desire to require relative to the base project directory.

This config is also specific to the application. Putting it in a module under `node_modules` is not something I want to do. I only put `npm` managed dependencies within `node_modules`.

My question is more about potential unexpected issues that could arise from relying on `process.mainModule` than it is about the `require` function.

Comment: `require('../../config')`?

Comment: @SLaks That makes the require dependent on the location of the `config.js` file. I updated my question with clarification.

Comment: I solved this issue (for config specifically) using the config module from npm. Now i can just `require('config')` and it will get it's config properties from my *"/config"* folder.

Comment: @KevinB thank you. I will consider adopting that module

Comment: Encountering the same problem, have you found some sort of better way to do it then do add something to your node_modules or to use relative paths ?

Comment: @edi9999 not in the spirit of the question, no. But using dependency injection solves the problem. It does require registering objects with a container, but it's better than hard coded paths all over the project -- http://npmjs.com/laic

Answer (score 0):

You could hard-code it like so

```
require('../../config')
```

Or, you could take advantage of the node_modules findup functionality in Node, and move `config.json` to `node_modules/config/index.json`

```
root/
|
-- app.js
-- node_modules
   |
   -- config
      |
       -- package.json
       -- index.json
-- package.json
-- lib/
   |
   -- config/
      |
      -- config.js
```

Then just use

```
require('config')
```

Comment: Neither of those approaches works for me. I have updated the question with clarification as to why.

Comment: Encountering the same problem, have you found some sort of better way to do it then do add something to your node_modules or to use relative paths ?